# How to get a non-minified version of d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a complete javascript newbie.

How can I get a non minified version of d3.js?

I have run across a script that interests me
and am able to run it in my browser, however
it uses a minified version of the d3.js.

I would like to step into the d3.js code in
the debugger but without meaningful names it
is very frustrating.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3/ am I missing something here? You want to step with the debugger into the non-obfuscated version? I'm not sure it can be easily done (like i.e: replacing the source with the unminified version...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is here:

https://github.com/d3/d3

And as far as I can see there is a vaild src map in this distro (taken from the README):

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm

So if you use that minified version you should be able to see eventual errors etc listed in the unminified source code

Comment: Good luck with your d3 endeavours Jeff! :)